# Angular Reactive Form - filter search results

Tags: angular, search, filter, dropdown

I have a dropdown with user names. I would like to make it into a search-as-you-type control. How can I achieve that? I am doing it using Angular 4 reactive form.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="detailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User:</label>
        <select formControlName="user" id="user" >
            <option *ngFor="let user of users"
                [value]="user.id">
                {{user.displayName}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

component:

```
getUsers() {
    this.service.getUsers()
        .subscribe(rems => this.users = rems);
}
```

Comment: This article may help: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and i use [ngx library](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/) and its components to use bootstrap components in my app. In particular, you can use [TypeHead](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead) component to have the desidered functionality